# FoxPro ERP throwing "Numeric Overflow" error. No support

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

So, a company I work at has an older ERP system that uses FoxPro 4 or 5. There is no support for the system, so I am trying to use skills that I don't possess. I'm good with Servers and even networks, but not coding. I have attached links to two similar errors that are occuring to two different users in different departments using different computers. Your help would be appreciated.

[FoxPro Error 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfauff964rve5ze/foxpro_error1.txt?dl=0)

[FoxPro Error 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmjldzaxqoihb84/foxpro_error2.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 6):

Well, the problem is exactly what it says on the tin. It looks like the issue is with the field BODY.COST. The field will have a maximum capacity, for example N(12, 2) would allow numbers up to 999999999.99 to be stored in it.

The system is attempting to put a number that is bigger than the defined capacity into this field. You can see it is a GATHER MEMVAR statement in both cases. This statement takes memory variables and updates a database table using them. One of the memory variables has ended up with a bigger number in it than the database field (looks like BODY.COST) that is intended to store it has capacity for.

Beyond that, with no support and no source code you are really limited to looking at what the user is trying to post and seeing if that gives you any clues. Is that the extent of the error dumps or are those just snippets?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yea, I've come across a similar error in SQL. I was able to open the MAIN4.PRG and SLSJRNL.PRG with Visual Studio and saved the info to text files. If you don't mind, I've included the Dropbox link to that folder. Again, I appreciate all your input and help. [Error Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fif46jc03bk169b/AABiLr3Iwq-HLuZAn6R6RpH-a?dl=0)

Answer (score 3):

The messages are saying that you are trying to store a larger value than the field would accept. This happens with numeric and float fields in Foxpro. In both of the messages, the table was indirectly aliased as "BODY" and the problematic field is "COST".

As a solution, using VFP5 (do not use a later version - there weren't VFP4), you can make all the numeric and float fields to either Currency or Double data type.
Currency has a high certainity and suggested for monetary values (need not be monetary). It is in the range of  –922337203685477.5808 to 922337203685477.5807. That range is actually above what a numeric/float field can support.

If you think that is not enough range, than you can use double (something like -10^327 to 10^304 - VFP has a precision of 15 digits, you lose precision beyond that).

I would go with Currency.